# Something is being delayed before the boolean that tells it to delay is being true

Tags: processing

I am making a pong game. When the ball goes past a paddle, i want it to reset the position of the ball to the middle, then delay(1000). I have two booleans that have to be true in order for it to work, however, it is still going off with only one or no booleans being true. Why is this happening?
code:

```
Paddle m;
Paddle o;
Ball b;
float sizeX;
float circleX = 800/2;
float circleY;
float xSpeed;
float ySpeed = 3;
float yAcceleration = -1;
float xAcceleration = -1;
boolean reset = true;
boolean point = false;
boolean y = false;
boolean s = false;
int u = 60;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  m = new Paddle();
  o = new Paddle();
  b = new Ball();
}

void draw() {
  frameRate(u);
  background(0);
  b.startVel();  
  b.ballProp();
  m.mPaddle();
  o.oPaddle();
  o.oPaddleProp();
  b.yBounce();
  m.mPaddleProp();
  o.oChange();
  b.displayScore();
  m.resetW();
  m.resetL();
  println(circleX);
}

//seperate tab
class Ball {

  float Color = (255);
  float circleDimensions = 32;
  int score = 0;

  void ballProp() {
    fill(Color);
    ellipse(circleX, circleY, circleDimensions, circleDimensions);
    circleX += xSpeed;
    circleY += ySpeed;
  }
  void startVel() {
    if (reset == true) {
      if (point == true) {
        score += 1;
      }
      circleX = random(300, 500);
      circleY = random(32, height);
      xStartVel();
      yStartVel();
delay(1000);
      y = true;
      point = false;
      reset = false;
    }
  }
  void xStartVel() {
    if (random(1) < .5) {
      xSpeed = 3;
    } else {
      xSpeed = -3;
    }
  }
  void yStartVel() {
    if (random(1) < .5) {
      ySpeed = 3;
    } else {
      ySpeed = -3;
    }
  }
  void yBounce() {
    if (circleY > height - 10 || circleY < 10) {
      ySpeed = ySpeed * yAcceleration;
    }
  }
  void displayScore() {
    fill(0, 102, 153);
    textSize(32);
    text(score, 10, 30);
  }
}
//seperate tab
class Paddle {

  float paddleColor = 255;
  float mPaddleX = 790;
  float oPaddleX = 10;
  float oPaddleY = 250;
  float PaddleWidth = 10;
  float paddleLength = 100;
  float change = 2;

  void mPaddle() {
    fill(paddleColor);
    rect(mPaddleX, mouseY, PaddleWidth, paddleLength);
  }
  void oPaddle() {
    fill(paddleColor);
    rect(oPaddleX, oPaddleY, PaddleWidth * -1, paddleLength);
  }
  void mPaddleProp() {
    if (circleY >= mouseY && circleY <= mouseY + paddleLength && circleX <= mPaddleX && mPaddleX - 10 <= circleX) {
      xSpeed = xSpeed * xAcceleration;
    }
  }
  void oPaddleProp() {
    if (circleY >= oPaddleY && circleY <= oPaddleY + paddleLength && oPaddleX <= circleX && circleX <= oPaddleX + PaddleWidth) {
      xSpeed = xSpeed * xAcceleration;
    }
  }
  void oChange() {
    if (circleY < oPaddleY + (paddleLength/2)) {
      oPaddleY += change * -1;
    } else if (circleY > oPaddleY - (paddleLength/2)) {
      oPaddleY += change;
    }
  }

  void resetW() {
    if (circleX < oPaddleX) {
      point = true;
      reset = true;
    }
  }
  void resetL() {
    if (circleX > mPaddleX) {
      reset = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The screen gets updated at the end of `draw()`, so the delay has to occur after the ball has been drawn at the reset position, or else the entire redrawn is delayed.

This is how you can solve this:
Add a new variable

```
boolean doDelay = false;
```

At the start of `draw`, check if there needs to be a delay

```
void draw() {
    if(doDelay){
    delay(1000);
    doDelay = false;
  }
[rest of code]
```

When a reset occurs, set doDelay to true

```
  void startVel() {
    if (reset == true) {
          doDelay = true;
    [rest of code]
```

At the start of the next frame, there will be a delay